# Is there a difference between "supplicant" and "sycophant"?

Tags: difference, usage, vocabulary

Cambridge Dictionary defines "supplicant" as:

- a person who asks a god or someone who is in a position of power for
  something in a humble way

whereas the same dictionary defines "sycophant" as:

- someone who praises powerful or rich people in a way that is not
  sincere, usually in order to get some advantage from them:

These words to seem to give off the impression of someone asking a powerful or rich person for favors. But I can't tell what that difference is. Perhaps a supplicant is someone who just simply asks for help because they have no other choice; they are afflicted by a problem they cannot solve on their own and requests assistance from someone who has the means or the knowledge to resolve the aggrieved person's problem. Whereas a sycophant is a bootlicker; someone who intentionally acts subservient with a powerful/rich person in exchange for favors? I could be wrong, but let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

They both start with an 's' and end '-ant'. They are both mainly used about a relationship between a weaker or lower-status person and someone stronger or higher status. Apart from that, they have distinct and separate meanings.

A supplicant is simply someone who asks for something. A requester. It could be a beggar asking for money or food, or a poor person asking a richer relative for money or help, or a job, etc.

A sycophant is someone who always praises and agrees with a more powerful or more important person, the boss, a powerful relative, etc, not because they genuinely agree with that person, but usually because they think it will help them in some way, e.g. advance their career. Other terms for this type of person (who is generally despised) include 'boot licker', ass-licker' and 'brown-noser'.